# Error while using handlers in Ansible

Tags: linux, unix, ansible, redhat, devops

```
---
- name: Oracle DB Prereqs
  hosts: sandbox
  become: true
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
      shmall_ent: 16384
      shmall_mid: 32768
      shmall_lar: 65536
      shmall_exlar: 262144

   tasks:
    - name: SHMALL value to set for memory size less than 16G
      when: ansible_memtotal_mb <= {{ shmall_ent }}
      notify:
        - SHMALL ent

    - name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 16G and 32G
      when: (ansible_memtotal_mb > {{ shmall_ent }} and ansible_memtotal_mb <= {{ shmall_mid }})|int
      notify:
        - SHMALL mid

    - name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 32G and 64G
      when: (ansible_memtotal_mb > {{ shmall_mid }} and ansible_memtotal_mb <= {{ shmall_lar }})|int
      notify:
        - SHMALL lar

    - name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 64G and 256G
      when: (ansible_memtotal_mb > {{ shmall_lar }} and ansible_memtotal_mb <= {{ shmall_exlar }})|int
      notify:
        - SHMALL exlar
      handlers:
    - name: SHMALL ent
      sysctl:
        name: kernel.shmall
        value: 3670016
        sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
    - name: SHMALL mid
      sysctl:
       name: kernel.shmall
       value: 7340032
       sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
    - name: SHMALL lar
      sysctl:
       name: kernel.shmall
       value: 14680064
       sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
    - name: SHMALL exlar
      sysctl:
       name: kernel.shmall
       value: 57671680
       sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
```

Error while running the play is:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/rjoy/ansible/roles/oracle/playbook/oraunix.yml': line 12, column 4, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


   tasks:
   ^ here
```

Answer (score 1):

Most syntax errors for Yaml are because of incorrect indentation because Yaml relies on whitespace.

See this example from the [playbook documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html):

```yaml
---
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    http_port: 80
    max_clients: 200
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    yum: name=httpd state=latest
  - name: write the apache config file
    template: src=/srv/httpd.j2 dest=/etc/httpd.conf
    notify:
    - restart apache
  - name: ensure apache is running (and enable it at boot)
    service: name=httpd state=started enabled=yes
  handlers:
    - name: restart apache
      service: name=httpd state=restarted
```

Notice how `tasks` is indented to the same level as `hosts` and `vars` and `remote_user`?

Also see how the items in the `tasks` array have the dash (`-`) indented to the same level as the word "tasks".

This indentation is important because that's how Yaml determines what elements belong to other elements. If you don't have everything indented correctly, it doesn't know how to parse it.

So this should work for you

```yaml
---
- name: Oracle DB Prereqs
  hosts: sandbox
  become: true
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    shmall_ent: 16384
    shmall_mid: 32768
    shmall_lar: 65536
    shmall_exlar: 262144

  tasks:
  - name: SHMALL value to set for memory size less than 16G
    when: ansible_memtotal_mb <= {{ shmall_ent }}
    notify:
      - SHMALL ent

  - name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 16G and 32G
    when: (ansible_memtotal_mb > {{ shmall_ent }} and ansible_memtotal_mb <= {{ shmall_mid }})|int
    notify:
      - SHMALL mid

  - name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 32G and 64G
    when: (ansible_memtotal_mb > {{ shmall_mid }} and ansible_memtotal_mb <= {{ shmall_lar }})|int
    notify:
      - SHMALL lar

  - name: SHMALL value to set for memory size between 64G and 256G
    when: (ansible_memtotal_mb > {{ shmall_lar }} and ansible_memtotal_mb <= {{ shmall_exlar }})|int
    notify:
      - SHMALL exlar

  handlers:
    - name: SHMALL ent
      sysctl:
        name: kernel.shmall
        value: 3670016
        sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf

    - name: SHMALL mid
      sysctl:
        name: kernel.shmall
        value: 7340032
        sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf

    - name: SHMALL lar
      sysctl:
        name: kernel.shmall
        value: 14680064
        sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf

    - name: SHMALL exlar
      sysctl:
        name: kernel.shmall
        value: 57671680
        sysctl_file: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me to optimize the script i mentioned above?

Comment: See my edit. All you had to do was remove a couple extra spaces at the start of a few lines.

Comment: The script works good. Now i need to add kernel.shmmax value with the same conditional statements will it work with multiple entries on to sysctl file upon a those conditions? @Yep_It's_Me

Comment: Sorry @Glaldiator I have no idea. I haven't done any work with sysctl files before. Just give it aa shot and if it gives you an error search for it on SO :)